# Remove legend in ggplot in Python

Tags: python, ggplot2, visualization, python-ggplot

The title says it all: Is there any way to remove the legend in ggplot in Python? I tried to google but could only find the solution for R

Answer (score 0):

Use `show_legend=False` argument, e.g.:

```
ggplot(s_df, aes(x_var, y_var, group = var3, fill = var3)) + geom_point(size = 4, show_legend=False)
```